# how to set globstar for noninteractive shells

Tags: bash, ssh, wildcards

I would like to execute commands noninteractively on a remote server that use the [**](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) globstar option.  However, globstar is not set by default on the remote, and [bash doesn't source any files in noninteractive mode](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BashInitialisationFiles.html), so I can't add this option to `~/.profile`.

Suppose on the remote server

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ mkdir -p a/b/c
$ ls a/**
a/:
b

a/b:
c
```

but remotely,

```
$ ssh user@remote "ls a**"
a/:
b
```

How can I enable globstar, ideally by changing the configuration on the remote machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the remote user is using `bash` then `$HOME/.bashrc` should be loaded, even in non-interactive shells.  You can put your options there.

e.g.

```
$ head -1 .bashrc 
echo BASHRC loaded

$ ssh localhost echo hello
sweh@localhost's password: 
BASHRC loaded
hello

$
```

Comment: why, so it does.  and I had `shopt -s globstar` after the bit that said 'stop if not interactive'.